# Where could we find tutorials about using the graspit_simulator?

Tags: ros, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

Where could we find tutorials about using the graspit_simulator stack?

I have checked it out from [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/), but still do not know where to start; given that there is no tutorial link on [its wiki](http://ros.org/wiki/graspit_simulator). (I am using Fuerte)

Any help please.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38430/where-could-we-find-tutorials-about-using-the-graspit_simulator?/) by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is now some additional documentation on the graspit_simulator Wiki page:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/graspit_simulator

It is not much, but might get you started. As for GraspIt! itself, the user manual linked in the answer above is the best source.

The next step would be to fully document the process by which GraspIt! is used in ROS to generate grasps for the household_objects_database. Unfortunately, I am not sure when I can finish that. All the functionality is in the stack though, and the code is generally commented, so you might be able to get that running.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think there are tutorial on graspit. If you are looking to learn about it, try the user manual at

[http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cmatei/graspit/html-manual/graspit-manual.html](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecmatei/graspit/html-manual/graspit-manual.html)

Or check with Matei

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1